# error creating overlay failed to mount overlay: permission denied

Tags: docker, kubernetes, virtual-machine, overlay, docker-daemon

I wanna change docker storage drive to overlay2 for use kubernetes

daemon.json :

```
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

but the service cannot start

journalctl -b -u docker.service:

```
level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: permission denied" storage-drive
May 05 05:35:32 master1 dockerd[492]: failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed my dockerd version from 5.19.3 to 5.19.5 (ubuntu) and that problem fixed and docker worked on overlay2 storage mode

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:19.03.5~3-0~ubuntu-xenial
```